# How to automate creating multiple bids for an auction smart contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, auctions

I have created a simple auction smart contract in remix and now I have to do some experiments with it. In my model, it is possible to create the requests and then bid those requests with the Bid() function. I want to create let's say 10 requests and then 20/200/2000 bids (from different users) for those requests to see how the system will work, if it is reliable and to measure time and gas cost. But I am not sure how I can automate the process of creating so many bids.

Does anybody know how it could be done ??
I would appreciate any sort of advice

Answer (score 0):

With the contract address and abi it is possible to automate requests creation from programming language like python or javascript.